# Google Play Developer Console: неактивна кнопка "Перейти на бета-тестирование для группы или сообщества"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Коллеги, всем качественного кода.
Сегодня утром по Москве зарегистрировал аккаунт разработчика. Цель - производить бета-тестирование приложения и обновлений к нему посредством участников сообщества в Google+.
Итак, в консоли разработчика заполнены все поля, отвечены все вопросы, подписанный .apk добавлен; также от учетной записи разработчика создан круг в Google+ и сообщество.
Через сообщество в Google+ отправил приглашение тестовому пользователю. Прошло больше полудня, тестовому пользователю приглашение так и не пришло.
Выбрал вкладку "Бета-тестирование" в разделе "Файлы APK" консоли разработчика.
Нажал на кнопку "Перейти на бета-тестирование для группы или сообщества". После чего ввел в поле электронный адрес тестового пользователя. В поле была прописана подсказка насчет ввода электронного адреса пользователя. Но пользователь так и не был найден. Попробовал несколько раз и после обновления страницы кнопка перестала отвечать на нажатия. Чуть позже я прочитал о формате ввода (приведен фрагмент с официального ресурса):

> Введите адрес электронной почты группы Google или URL сообщества
>   Google+, используя следующие форматы: Для группы Google:
>   nazvanie_gruppy@googlegroups.com Для сообщества Google+:
>   https://plus.google.com/communities/123456789012345678901

Жаль, что подобная подсказка не приведена непосредственно рядом с полем...
Честно говоря, не знаю, что и думать: в мануалах и тру-стори написано жать кнопку "Перейти на бета-тестирование для группы или сообщества" и приглашать пользователей, выслав им ссылку. Но кнопка почему-то не реагирует на нажатия.
Может, кто разумеет?

Comment: Сегодня утром кнопка оказалась разблокированной...

Comment: Видимо, это временная блокировка, связанная с несколькими неудачными попытками выбора нужного сообщества в Google+

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос можно считать закрытым - весьма вероятно, что ситуация была связана с несколькими неудачными попытками выбора нужного сообщества в Google+ и, возможно, проверкой данных.